# change excel page size with combobox selection change

Tags: excel, vba, windows, printing

I have created a custom page size for excel under "windows print server properties". following the steps given here https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/pdf-custom-paper-windows-10.html

Now I have all the custom sizes including default sizes shown in the excel page size list. next, I have pulled all sizes to excel Combobox dropdown with the following codes.

so my requirement is to change excel sheet size with Combobox selection change.

**Please Note: we cannot change size with case method or predefine it unless sizes are fixed, as sizes will be dynamic in Combobox, once the user creates a new size it ll get added to Combobox.**

Thanks

```
'worksheet code
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.List = GetPaperSizes
```

'module code

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Const DC_PAPERNAMES = &H10

    Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities _
      Lib "winspool.drv" _
        Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesA" _
          (ByVal lpDeviceName As String, _
           ByVal lpPort As String, _
           ByVal iIndex As Long, _
           ByRef lpOutput As Any, _
           ByRef lpDevMode As Any) _
        As Long

    Private Declare Function StrLen _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" _
        Alias "lstrlenA" _
          (ByVal lpString As String) _
        As Long

    Function GetPaperSizes() As Variant

        Dim AllNames As String
        Dim I As Long
        Dim Msg As String
        Dim PD As Variant
        Dim Ret As Long
        Dim papersizes() As Byte
        Dim PaperSize As String

        'Retrieve the number of available paper names
        PD = Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " on ")'<<<== change "on" with its local Language translation from english
        Ret = DeviceCapabilities(PD(0), PD(1), DC_PAPERNAMES, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)

        'resize the array
        ReDim papersizes(0 To Ret * 64) As Byte

        'retrieve all the available paper names
        Call DeviceCapabilities(PD(0), PD(1), DC_PAPERNAMES, papersizes(0), ByVal 0&)

        'convert the retrieved byte array to an ANSI string
        AllNames = StrConv(papersizes, vbUnicode)

         'loop through the string and search for the names of the papers
        For I = 1 To Len(AllNames) Step 64
            PaperSize = Mid(AllNames, I, 64)
            PaperSize = Left(PaperSize, StrLen(PaperSize))
            If PaperSize <> vbNullString Then Msg = Msg & PaperSize & vbCrLf
        Next I

        GetPaperSizes = Split(Left(Msg, Len(Msg) - 2), vbCrLf)

    End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can I expect any help on this? I am not sure this bump is right or not.